# Compile ASP.NET MVC Project in VS2013 doesn't work in release

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll, compilation, release

I tried to compile my ASP.NET c# project with VS 2013 in `Release` mode but I can't do this. During the compile process I obtain some error like that one

> Error 55  Could not copy
>   "\192.168.1.103\d$\ShareDLL\CommonTools\CommonTools20\CommonTools20.dll" to
>   "\192.168.1.103l\d$\ShareDLL\IndexCalculation\IndexCalculation\CommonTools20.dll".
>   Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

and then

> Error 56  Unable to copy file
>   "\192.168.1.103\d$\ShareDLL\CommonTools\CommonTools20\CommonTools20.dll" to
>   "\192.168.1.103l\d$\ShareDLL\IndexCalculation\IndexCalculation\CommonTools20.dll".
>   Impossibile trovare il percorso di rete.

for some libraries.
The problem is that if I compile the same project in `Debug` mode everything works fine.

I have to set something in VS?
Thanks

Comment: Something goes wrong with folder, you are publishing to. Try to close VS, remove folders "bin" and "obj" from your project root, and try to build again.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work. I have the same problem

Comment: Oh, are you copying from remote machine? \192.168.1.103\ Maybe remote access for user, which is used by VS is not granted? Try to refer this library locally. It is a strange way to refer library from remote machine in your project,

Comment: I copy the dll from a remote machine but the user have an access, otherwise it can't work if I copile in debug mode, or no?

Comment: It seems more like there are problems with remote machine. Maybe network? ALL debug-builds are succesfull and ALL release fail?

Comment: Yes, ALL deubu-builds are succesfull and ALL release fail

Answer (score 0):

I always resolve it like this:

1.Clean Solution (and do nothing else)

2.Close all open documents/files in the solution

3.Exit VS

4.Run VS

5.Build Solution

Dont know why it work, but work. (VS 2013 also)

Comment: Try befor cleaning solution, remove your all bins and objs. Also if you try public project remote, check if it work on local machine.